# Passed Pandas Dataframe to_string and want to remove leading and trailing apostrophe's

Tags: python, pandas

I have a sqlite3 database that i am using Pandas to pull values.  I want to pass these to Highcharts.  My challenge is that I cannot get rid of the leading and trailing apostrophe's in my .to_string output.

My abbreviated steps are:

- `ddt = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT sensor_id from humidities limit 10', con)`
- `ddtnb = ddt.to_string(header=False, index=False, index_names=False).split('\\r')`
- `vals = [",".join(ele.split()) for ele in ddtnb]`

my output for vals is:
`['35,35,35,35,35,36,35,35,36,35']`

I have tried everything but i cannot get rid of the leading and trailing apostrophe's.  Looking for guidance.  Thanks.

Comment: Could you please add **real code** that shows your problem and not only some rough idea of your code.

Comment: Sorry Tim was real code but burhan answer solved it perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to get a list of values you can simply try this:

```
ddt = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT sensor_id from humidities limit 10', con)
ddt.ix[:,0].tolist()
```

or if you want values as comma separated string try this:

```
','.join(map(str, ddt.ix[:,0].tolist()))
```

Comment: Works Perfectly - just what i needed  - Thank you.